# Multiple OpenIdConnect authorization in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, authorization, openid

I have problem with having multiple OpenIdConnect authorization in .net core

**What I want to achieve:**
Imagine 2 openid providers OpenID-Main, OpenID-Special; both returns id tokens, roles etc.
Now Imagine most of the times I want my user to log through OpenID-Main, which is simple:

```
.AddOpenIdConnect("Main", "Main", options => {
              options.Authority = "OpenID-Main-url";
              options.ClientId = "OpenID-Main-d";
              options.ClientSecret = "OpenID-Main-secret";
//some other options
}
```

then i can just use **[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Main")]**
Which just works fine
Now for certain types of request i will require user to login to other provider (please don't argue aboat this approach, lets assume its something i have to do)

```
 .AddOpenIdConnect("Special", "Special", options => {
                  options.Authority = "OpenID-Special-url";
                  options.ClientId = "OpenID-Special-d";
                  options.ClientSecret = "OpenID-Special-secret";
    //some other options
    }
```

and then have both **[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Main")]** **[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Special")]** in one of my endponits
So that, only user authorized both in Main & Special can execute request, and i can get idToken from Special.

I go errors like Corellation failed. I've tried to provide siddwewnr CorrelationCookie.Name, but with no success; Tried to override some base auth classes but also stuck and copying multiple code parts.

**My questions are**

```
1. Is it ever possible with Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication ?
2. How can I achieve it? Can I do proper CookieBuilder for second auth?
3. How can I manage this easily so that I can get idToken from second cookie?
4. Do I need to write whole handler/extensions/options like those for facebook/google?
```

Comment: Corellation failed means the two do not have unique CallbackPath values, the wrong handler is intercepting the request.

Comment: That said, to be logged in with two providers at once you're going to need two auth cookies/scheme's and a custom login page. Trying to challenge for both directly from a controller won't work, they'll step on each other.

Comment: Shouldn't it create two cookies for each auth and if cookie exists for A, then check B? Also when I have different CallbackPath it keeps stuck in redirection to 2nd provider (cookie created in first stays, but no additional cookie after login from second)

Comment: Show the rest of your auth config from Startup.

Answer (score 0):

For each provider Setup Unique Cookie, CallbackPath, Setup SigninScheme for Cookie per provider:

```
.AddCookie($"Cookie{provider}") 
.AddOpenIdConnect($"Sign{provider}", o=>{
    o.CallbackPath=$"/sign-{provider}";
    o.SinginScheme=$"/Cookie{provider}";
})
```

Now each [Authorize] will have its own claims, so can't setup twice [Authorize], but can have main one, and do check manually:

```
var auth = await context.AuthenticateAsync($"Sign{provider}").ConfigureAwait(false);
if(auth==null){
    await context.ChallengeAsync($"Sign{provider}").ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/47013455/2) to the question [Multiple OpenIdConnect authorization in .net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47013455/multiple-openidconnect-authorization-in-net-core) by the OP [maque](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3338112/maque) under CC BY-SA 3.0.</sub>